# Help Me Minimize Freezer Burn on Ice Cream by Understanding Transcendental Equations

Tags: integration, transcendental-equations

I'm a high school math teacher trying to stay engaged with the subject, and I've started wondering about this question:

"Given a cylindrical ice cream container with radius *r* and height *h*, determine the best way to scoop out a given volume *s* of ice cream in order to minimize the surface area that you expose."

If we can solve this problem, we can minimize freezer burn, which is inversely proportional to ice cream enjoyment. The impact could be huge.

**My Question:**

While investigating a certain scooping method that I believe to be optimal for many containers and scoop sizes, I eventually stumbled upon this equation as a solution to a relevant indefinite integral:
$$
\frac{s}{h}-\frac{\pi r^2}{2}=r^2\arcsin \left( \frac{x}{r} \right) + x\sqrt{r^2-x^2
}
$$
My goal is to solve this for *x*, but I'm really struggling. A bit of research has presented me with the idea that this is likely to be a "transcendental equation", which is likely to be unsolvable. But I'll be honest -- the idea of transcendental equations is new to me, and I don't exactly know where to go from here.

I'm wondering if you all can tell me whether this can be solved, and if so, how, and if not, why not?

I should mention that I already solved the integral with a Riemann sum, and that works perfectly fine for my purposes. But still... I'd like a perfect solution if there is one.

Thanks!

Comment: What area do you count?  It appears you only count new surface area, so the surface area against the container and the original top do not count.  Are you just scooping once, or do you count the total area after each of several servings?

Comment: @RossMillikan You're exactly right -- we will assume that the sides and the original top are safe from freezer burn. We are only interested in minimizing the newly exposed surface area. So far, I've investigated "disc method", where we take a flat disc off the top, "slice method", where we draw a chord through the circle and take everything (top to bottom) on one side of the chord, and "cylinder method", where we take a cylinder (top to bottom) from the center of the container. Each have proven to be optimal for different containers, but I suspect that there are other superior methods.

Comment: @RossMillikan As for the number of scoops, I'm thoroughly perplexed by taking only one, so for simplicity, that is the question I'm asking right now. That said, I would be interested to ask what method(s) would be optimal for taking consecutive scoops until the container is empty, but that seems a bit too difficult for me to tackle at the moment.

Comment: Try converting to polar equations.

Comment: lol your user name is funny :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that the equation to be solved for $x$ is
$$\frac{s}{h}-\frac{\pi r^2}{2}=r^2\arcsin \left( \frac{x}{r} \right) + x\sqrt{r^2-x^2}$$ let $$x=r t \qquad \text{and}\qquad k= \frac 1{r^2} \left(\frac{s}{h}-\frac{\pi r^2}{2}\right)$$ to make
$$k=\arcsin(t)+t\sqrt{1-t^2}$$

Expanded as a series
$$\arcsin(t)+t\sqrt{1-t^2}=2t-\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{|a_n|}{b_n} t^{2n+1}$$ where
the $a_n$ and $b_n$ form sequences $A091154$
and  $A143582$ in $OEIS$.

Using series reversion, we have
$$t=\frac{k}{2}+\frac{k^3}{48}+\frac{13 k^5}{3840}+\frac{493 k^7}{645120}+\frac{37369
   k^9}{185794560}+\frac{4732249 k^{11}}{81749606400}+$$ $$\frac{901188997
   k^{13}}{51011754393600}+\frac{240798388357
   k^{15}}{42849873690624000}+\frac{6611433892597
   k^{17}}{3586204813492224000}+O\left(k^{19}\right)$$

Before trying to make simpler, check the results for e few values of $k$

$$\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
k & \text{estimate} & \text{solution} \\
 0.1 & 0.050021 &  0.050021 \\
 0.2 & 0.100168 &  0.100168 \\
 0.3 & 0.150571 &  0.150571 \\
 0.4 & 0.201369 &  0.201369 \\
 0.5 & 0.252716 &  0.252716 \\
 0.6 & 0.304787 &  0.304787 \\
 0.7 & 0.357787 &  0.357787 \\
 0.8 & 0.411969 &  0.411969 \\
 0.9 & 0.467654 &  0.467654 \\
 1.0 & 0.525267 &  0.525268 \\
 1.1 & 0.585404 &  0.585410 \\
 1.2 & 0.648947 &  0.648986 \\
 1.3 & 0.717288 &  0.717509 \\
 1.4 & 0.792768 &  0.793961 \\
 1.5 & 0.879532 &  0.886571
\end{array}
\right)$$

which seems to be more than decent up to $k \sim 1.4$.

Let $t_0$ to be the above estimate. Polish the root using a couple of Newton iterations;

**Edit**

Using Padé approximants, we have

$$\arcsin(t)+t\sqrt{1-t^2}=\frac{2 t \left(60-19 t^2\right)}{60-9 t^2}+O\left(t^7\right)$$

In fact, compared to the series, this is in an error of $\frac{29 t^7}{2800}$

Solving the cubic equation
$$38 t^3-9 k t^2-120 t+60k=0$$ which shows three real roots but the one to be retained is
$$t=\frac{1}{38} \left(3 k-2 \sqrt{9 k^2+1520} \cos \left(\frac{1}{3} \left(\cos
   ^{-1}\left(-\frac{3 k \left(12160-9 k^2\right)}{\left(9
   k^2+1520\right)^{3/2}}\right)+\pi \right)\right)\right)$$

$$\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
k & \text{estimate} & \text{solution} \\
 0.1 & 0.050021 &  0.050021 \\
 0.2 & 0.100168 &  0.100168 \\
 0.3 & 0.150571 &  0.150571 \\
 0.4 & 0.201369 &  0.201369 \\
 0.5 & 0.252716 &  0.252716 \\
 0.6 & 0.304785 &  0.304787 \\
 0.7 & 0.357783 &  0.357787 \\
 0.8 & 0.411956 &  0.411969 \\
 0.9 & 0.467620 &  0.467654 \\
 1.0 & 0.525185 &  0.525268 \\
 1.1 & 0.585212 &  0.585410 \\
 1.2 & 0.648520 &  0.648986 \\
 1.3 & 0.716387 &  0.717509 \\
 1.4 & 0.791046 &  0.793961 \\
 1.5 & 0.877156 &  0.886571
\end{array}
\right)$$

Same quality but nicer formula.

Comment: There is a problem Claude ...you have a palindromic reputation :-)

Comment: @ErikSatie. Could you explain ? I do not see what it means. Cheers :-)

Comment: Claude, he means that your MSE rep score (222k) is a palindrome - 222 backwards is 222.

Comment: @ErikSatie. I was thinking about THAT reputation

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici sorry I was kidding a little to be apologize see this : $$\left(\frac{24^{\frac{1}{16}}}{\ln4}\right)!-\frac{3}{\pi}>0$$

Comment: @ErikSatie. No problem at all ! I really did not understand. Cheers :-)

Comment: @ErikSatie  tomorrow I shall bé in .... Your housse, listening your music

Comment: You need an infinite code to enter it's : $$\left(\frac{S^{2}}{6}!\right)^{\frac{1}{\left(\frac{S^{2}}{6}!-\frac{1}{\frac{S^{2}}{6}!}\right)}}-\frac{\left(1+\sqrt{5}\right)}{2}$$ where $S$ is the Silver constant .

Answer (score 2):

If the rule is you only serve once and only count newly exposed surface, for small servings the optimum will be to remove a hemisphere as we know a sphere has the smallest area for its volume.  When the area of the hemisphere gets greater than the area of the container you should change to removing a cylinder from the top, leaving a surface the area of the base of the container.  This stays optimum until you are removing so much that the remainder can be packed into a sphere with smaller area than the base, at which point you should do that.

Comment: I thought a lot about this exact method when I was starting this problem. While a sphere does have minimum surface area for 3D solids, we need to keep in mind that we are not restricted to 3D solids. We could easily leave ourselves with a 2D rectangle by taking a slice out of the side (see "slice method" from my comment to you above). While a hemisphere may be optimal sometimes, from what I can gather, we cannot rely on it always being optimal. That said, I'm a bit out of my league here, so I could be in error. Either way, thanks for you reply!

Comment: I don't think the slice method will ever be best.  For small volumes it has one dimension that is much too large, making more surface area.  The cylinder method will work well in short containers.

Comment: Alrighty, update. I have been using a Google Sheet to run the numbers for different methods after adjusting the parameters. Since receiving your input, I added a "Hemisphere Method", and it seems to be optimal for small amounts of ice cream across the board. As you predicted, disc method remains optimal for tall containers, and cylinder method for short, wide containers. Slice method, however, does work well for moderate amounts of ice cream out of moderately shaped containers. Interesting! https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1x5O2kReoKQZB8TfSVHLCl5s-0wTPfbFhGgDFV9hPP0s/template/preview